# How to restart colord

Tags: restart, init.d

A tiff security update came out today for 12.04 and colord is still running with the older shared library

```
# lsof -n | grep DEL | grep /lib
colord     3454           colord  DEL       REG              252,1               3673529 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4
```

Besides restarting the whole system, given there's no /etc/init.d/colord, how do I restart it so it picks up the new libtiff.so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
killall colord gnome-settings-daemon
```

`gnome-settings-daemon` will restart and that will restart `colord`.

Comment: Kill `colord` as root, wait for it to die, then kill `gnome-settings-daemon` and wait for it to die, then start it again if it does not restart by itself: `sudo killall -w colord; killall -w gnome-settings-daemon; sleep 1; gnome-settings-daemon &`